# Setting up a forward proxy using Apache Traffic Server which forwards all request to another proxy and caches responses

Tags: proxy, apache-traffic-server

Setting up a forward proxy using Apache Traffic Server which forwards all request to another proxy and caches responses. I want to setup caching in front of my crawlers so that unwanted js and CSS requests can be cached all the time. I already have a setup where a load balancer is forwarding proxy requests to the setup of proxy services. I want to put ATS between the crawlers and load balancer. My current ATS records.config and parent.config are given below.

Currently when I try to do this,  curl --proxy localhost:8080 "https://exmaple.com/path" I get this error : curl: (56) Received HTTP code 502 from proxy after CONNECT

Here is my parent.config
`dest_domains=. parent="localhost:3128;" round_robin=strict`

Here is my records.config

```
##############################################################################
# *NOTE*: All options covered in this file should be documented in the docs:
#
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/reference/configuration/records.config.en.html
##############################################################################
##############################################################################
# Thread configurations. Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#proxy-config-exec-thread-autoconfig
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.exec_thread.autoconfig INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.exec_thread.autoconfig.scale FLOAT 1.500000
CONFIG proxy.config.exec_thread.limit INT 2
CONFIG proxy.config.ssl.number.threads INT 0
CONFIG proxy.config.accept_threads INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.task_threads INT 2
CONFIG proxy.config.cache.threads_per_disk INT 8
    # https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#proxy-config-exec-thread-affinity
CONFIG proxy.config.exec_thread.affinity INT 0
##############################################################################
# Specify server addresses and ports to bind for HTTP and HTTPS. Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#proxy-config-http-server-ports
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.http.server_ports STRING 8080
##############################################################################
# Via: headers. Docs:
#     https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#proxy-config-http-insert-response-via-str
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.http.insert_request_via_str INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.http.insert_response_via_str INT 0
##############################################################################
# Parent proxy configuration, in addition to these settings also see parent.config. Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#parent-proxy-configuration
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/reference/configuration/parent.config.en.html
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.http.parent_proxy_routing_enable INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.http.parent_proxy.retry_time INT 300
CONFIG proxy.config.http.parent_proxy.connect_attempts_timeout INT 30
CONFIG proxy.config.http.forward.proxy_auth_to_parent INT 0
CONFIG proxy.config.http.uncacheable_requests_bypass_parent INT 1
##############################################################################
# HTTP connection timeouts (secs). Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#http-connection-timeouts
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.http.keep_alive_no_activity_timeout_in INT 115
CONFIG proxy.config.http.keep_alive_no_activity_timeout_out INT 120
CONFIG proxy.config.http.transaction_no_activity_timeout_in INT 30
CONFIG proxy.config.http.transaction_no_activity_timeout_out INT 30
CONFIG proxy.config.http.transaction_active_timeout_in INT 900
CONFIG proxy.config.http.transaction_active_timeout_out INT 0
CONFIG proxy.config.http.accept_no_activity_timeout INT 120
CONFIG proxy.config.net.default_inactivity_timeout INT 86400
##############################################################################
# Origin server connect attempts. Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#origin-server-connect-attempts
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.http.connect_attempts_max_retries INT 6
CONFIG proxy.config.http.connect_attempts_max_retries_dead_server INT 3
CONFIG proxy.config.http.connect_attempts_rr_retries INT 3
CONFIG proxy.config.http.connect_attempts_timeout INT 30
CONFIG proxy.config.http.post_connect_attempts_timeout INT 1800
CONFIG proxy.config.http.down_server.cache_time INT 300
CONFIG proxy.config.http.down_server.abort_threshold INT 10
##############################################################################
# Negative response caching, for redirects and errors. Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#negative-response-caching
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.http.negative_caching_enabled INT 0
CONFIG proxy.config.http.negative_caching_lifetime INT 1800
##############################################################################
# Proxy users variables. Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#proxy-user-variables
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.http.anonymize_insert_client_ip INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.http.insert_squid_x_forwarded_for INT 1
##############################################################################
# Security. Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#security
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.http.push_method_enabled INT 0
##############################################################################
# Enable / disable HTTP caching. Useful for testing, but also as an
# overridable (per remap) config
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.http INT 1
##############################################################################
# Cache control. Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#cache-control
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/reference/configuration/cache.config.en.html
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.ignore_client_cc_max_age INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.http.normalize_ae_gzip INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.cache_responses_to_cookies INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.cache_urls_that_look_dynamic INT 1
    # https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#proxy-config-http-cache-when-to-revalidate
CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.when_to_revalidate INT 0
    # https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#proxy-config-http-cache-required-headers
CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.required_headers INT 0
##############################################################################
# Heuristic cache expiration. Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#heuristic-expiration
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.heuristic_min_lifetime INT 3600
CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.heuristic_max_lifetime INT 86400
CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.heuristic_lm_factor FLOAT 0.100000
##############################################################################
# Network. Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#network
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.net.connections_throttle INT 30000
##############################################################################
# RAM and disk cache configurations. Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#ram-cache
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/reference/configuration/storage.config.en.html
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.cache.ram_cache.size INT -1
CONFIG proxy.config.cache.ram_cache_cutoff INT 4194304
    # https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#proxy-config-cache-limits-http-max-alts
CONFIG proxy.config.cache.limits.http.max_alts INT 5
    # https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#proxy-config-cache-max-doc-size
CONFIG proxy.config.cache.max_doc_size INT 0
CONFIG proxy.config.cache.min_average_object_size INT 8000
##############################################################################
# Logging Config. Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#logging-configuration
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/reference/configuration/logs_xml.config.en.html
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.log.logging_enabled INT 3
CONFIG proxy.config.log.max_space_mb_for_logs INT 2000
CONFIG proxy.config.log.max_space_mb_headroom INT 1000
CONFIG proxy.config.log.squid_log_enabled INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.log.squid_log_is_ascii INT 0
CONFIG proxy.config.log.rolling_enabled INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.log.rolling_interval_sec INT 86400
CONFIG proxy.config.log.rolling_size_mb INT 10
CONFIG proxy.config.log.auto_delete_rolled_files INT 1
##############################################################################
# These settings control remapping, and if the proxy allows (open) forward proxy or not. Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#url-remap-rules
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/reference/configuration/remap.config.en.html
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.url_remap.remap_required INT 0
    # https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#proxy-config-url-remap-pristine-host-hdr
CONFIG proxy.config.url_remap.pristine_host_hdr INT 0
    # https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#reverse-proxy
CONFIG proxy.config.reverse_proxy.enabled INT 0
##############################################################################
# SSL Termination. Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#client-related-configuration
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/reference/configuration/ssl_multicert.config.en.html
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.ssl.client.verify.server INT 0
CONFIG proxy.config.ssl.client.CA.cert.filename STRING NULL
CONFIG proxy.config.ssl.server.cipher_suite STRING ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA!SRP:!DSS:!PSK:!aNULL:!eNULL:!SSLv2
##############################################################################
# ICP Configuration. Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#icp-configuration
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/reference/configuration/icp.config.en.html
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.icp.enabled INT 0
##############################################################################
# Debugging. Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#diagnostic-logging-configuration
##############################################################################
CONFIG proxy.config.diags.debug.enabled INT 0
CONFIG proxy.config.diags.debug.tags STRING http.*|dns.*
# ToDo: Undocumented
CONFIG proxy.config.dump_mem_info_frequency INT 0
CONFIG proxy.config.http.slow.log.threshold INT 0
##############################################################################
# Cluster Subsystem. Docs:
#    https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/records.config#cluster
##############################################################################
LOCAL proxy.local.cluster.type INT 3
CONFIG proxy.config.cluster.ethernet_interface STRING lo
CONFIG proxy.config.cluster.cluster_port INT 8086
CONFIG proxy.config.cluster.rsport INT 8088
CONFIG proxy.config.cluster.mcport INT 8089
CONFIG proxy.config.cluster.mc_group_addr STRING 224.0.1.37
CONFIG proxy.config.body_factory.template_sets_dir STRING /etc/trafficserver/body_factory
CONFIG proxy.config.url_remap.filename STRING remap.config
CONFIG proxy.config.http_ui_enabled INT 1

CONFIG proxy.config.admin.user_id STRING trafficserver
CONFIG proxy.config.http.no_dns_just_forward_to_parent INT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a different curl:

```
curl --resolve example.com:8080:127.0.0.1 "https://exmaple.com/path"
```

I've never had success using the `--proxy` option for https requests.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when using 127.0.0.1 or localhost as the proxy address I get
HTTP/1.1 502 Tunnel Connection Failed
but when using the fqdn or non-local ip address for the proxy things work much better.